# How to count markers within the user radius using geofire query in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps-markers, geofire

Here is my code I add marker to the location within the radius

```java
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation( new GeoLocation( latitude, longitude ), 1 );

HashMap<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap<>();

geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener( new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        countCrime++;

        if (isAttachedToActivity()) {

            //get string icon using filename
            int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    data.getIcon(), "drawable",
                    getActivity().getPackageName() );

            //bitmapDescriptor for marker using filename
            BitmapDescriptor crime_icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource( resourceID );

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( latitude, longitude );

            Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position( latLng )
                    .icon( crime_icon ) );
            markers.put( key, marker );
            
            marker.setTag( details );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Output:
[image: Here is the Output]

I want to count the marker in the radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to count the keys inside the geoquery, is to keep a counter variable and increase that every time `is called. Then when` is called to indicate that all keys have been loaded, you know how many there are.

In code:

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener( new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    int keyCount = 0; // 

    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        keyCount++; // 

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        keyCount--; // 
    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {
        System.out.println("There are now "+keyCount+" keys in range"); // 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can get now the number of keys and I want to pass that to other activity using intent but the value has been doubled. How to solve this?

Comment: That's a new problem, so you'll want to post a new question for that.